# Refreshing GPIO Pin Status Automatically On a Flask Server

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi

I am building a garage controller using Raspberry Pi with a Flask Server on it. Everything is working as expected except the fact that I still need to figure out how to automatically update the GPIO pin status and refresh the html page to open/close automatically.

I have attached my code below, any help would be appreciated.

The refresh status button you see right now is a workaround I created to refresh the page. But I am looking for something to refresh the page automatically per PIN status change.

***Flask Code***

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Status():
    if GPIO.input(16) == GPIO.LOW:
        app.logger.info('Gate is Closed')
        return render_template('Closed.html')
    elif GPIO.input(16) == GPIO.HIGH:
        app.logger.info('Gate is Open')
        return render_template('Open.html')


@app.route("/Open", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Open():
    GPIO.output(7, True)
    app.logger.info('Gate is Opening')
    return render_template('Open.html')


@app.route("/Closed", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Closed():
    GPIO.output(7, False)
    app.logger.info('Gate is Closing')
    return render_template('Closed.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**HTML Code for Closed**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" 
        content="1; url = /" />-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">-->
    <style>
        .switch {
          vertical-align: middle;
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 60px;
          height: 34px;
        }
        
        .switch input { 
          opacity: 0;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
        }
        
        .slider {
          position: absolute;
          cursor: pointer;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: #ccc;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
        }
        
        .slider:before {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          height: 26px;
          width: 26px;
          left: 4px;
          bottom: 4px;
          background-color: white;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
        }
        
        input:checked + .slider {
          background-color: #2196F3;
        }
        
        input:focus + .slider {
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }
        
        input:checked + .slider:before {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
          -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
          transform: translateX(26px);
        }
        
        /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
          border-radius: 34px;
        }
        
        .slider.round:before {
          border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .button {
            color: #fff !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: #000;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        }

        .sliderWrapper{display: inline-block;margin:24px 24px 24px 24px;position:relative;}
        .sliderWrapper div{display: inline-block;line-height:60px;}
        </style>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout (
                function() { window.location.reload(); },
                500
            )
      </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ff5c33">
    <center>
        <br>
        <h1>Gate Control</h1>
        <br><br> <br> <br>

        <h3>Use the toggle to Open/Close the Relay!</h3>
        <form action="/Open">
          <div class="sliderWrapper">
            <div>Close&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="submit();">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;Open&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="refresh">
        <br><br>

        <h3>Use the button to Refresh the Page/Status!</h3>
        <a href="/" class="button">Refresh</a>
        </div>
        
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

**HTML Code for Open**

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" 
        content="1; url = /" />-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">-->
    <style>
        .switch {
          vertical-align: middle;
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 60px;
          height: 34px;
        }
        
        .switch input { 
          opacity: 0;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
        }
        
        .slider {
          position: absolute;
          cursor: pointer;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: #ccc;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
        }
        
        .slider:before {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          height: 26px;
          width: 26px;
          left: 4px;
          bottom: 4px;
          background-color: white;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
        }
        
        input:checked + .slider {
          background-color: #2196F3;
        }
        
        input:focus + .slider {
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }
        
        input:checked + .slider:before {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
          -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
          transform: translateX(26px);
        }
        
        /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
          border-radius: 34px;
        }
        
        .slider.round:before {
          border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .button {
            color: #fff !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: #000;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        }
        .sliderWrapper{display: inline-block;margin:24px 24px 24px 24px;position:relative;}
        .sliderWrapper div{display: inline-block;line-height:60px;}
      </style>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            setTimeout (
                function() { window.location.reload(); },
                500
            )
      </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="lightgreen">
    <center>
        <br>
        <h1>Gate Control</h1>
        <br><br> <br> <br>

        <h3>Use the toggle to Open/Close the Relay!</h3>
        <form action="/Closed">
          <div class="sliderWrapper">
            <div>Close&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked onclick="submit();">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <div>&nbsp;&nbsp;Open&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="refresh">
        <br><br>

        <h3>Use the button to Refresh the Page/Status!</h3>
        <a href="/" class="button">Refresh</a>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into how HTTP works in the classic client server way.

- Your client in the front end request something from your server
- if the requested resource/page is available the server responds. and sends it back to client.
- Done

The above request/response cycle explains why your refresh button is needed.

In the past one way to work around this was to run some javascript/JQuery in the front end and periodically refresh the page (AJAX/long polling) And that will still work.

By now there are other ways too, for example use a (web)sockets to create a bi directional channel in which the server can push data to the client. Working around the problem you have with classic request/response. (Flask Socket IO for example)

Both ways are worth researching, but javascript to periodically poll will probably be the quickest if not the prettiest fix.